# System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary : how to access its members

Tags: .net, json, deserialization

i am learning, i have response from a REST API in jSON format and it is being recieved in s string named `filters`

what i am trying to do is de-serialize it so that i may use the data contained in jSON.. this is what i am doing

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedJson = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(filters);
```

now the thing is it is working but i don;t know how to further utilize it...

i debug-ed the de-serialization statement to find the following result

[image]

it says that it is that my reult object is of `{System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>}` type

[image]

what to do... i need extract the `property : Make` and `value : Honda`

there is the jSON which is being sent.. that is what is in `filters` sting `[{"property":"Make","value":"Honda"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to cast returned object to Dictionary, like this:

```
var deserializedJson = jsSerialize.DeserializeObject(filters);
var dictionary = (Dictionary<string,object>)deserializedJson;
```

Now, you can access any property by key:

```
object prop = dictionary["property"];
object make = dictionary["value"];
```

Note that "prop" and "make" are object variables, but I suspect that underlying type is a string. So you can just call .ToString() on both property and make to convert them to string.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be as below,

```
dynamic deserializedJson = jsSerialize.DeserializeObject(filters);
object prop = deserializedJson["property"];
object make = deserializedJson["value"];
```